# Django images upload fails

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am using django to upload a image to the database (POST request) and show the same in the site.
but for some reason my image is not uploading

> models.py -

```
from django.db import models


class image_classification(models.Model):
    pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import image_classification
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


# def home(request):
#     print('here you go ')
#     images=image_classification.objects.all()
#     url=images[len(images)-1].pic.url
#     return render(request,'home.html',{'print':'everything is ok','image':url})


def home(request):
    print('here you go ')
    images=[]
    images=image_classification.objects.all()

    if len(images) > 0:
     url=images[len(images)-1].pic.url
    else:
      url="place holder image url"
    return render(request,'home.html',{'print':'everything is ok','image':url})

#handles uploaded images
def uploadImage(request):
    print('image handling ')
    img= request.FILES['image']
    image=image_classification(pic=img)
    image.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

> url of the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home')
]

urlpatterns+= static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> url.py for project (incase you need this)

```
 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ImageClassifier import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ImageClassifier.urls')),
]
```

> lastly settings.py (not sure if this is needed)

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'ImageClassifier/media/')
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'


STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and this is the error i am getting on the webpage while running

[image]

Comment: Can you also share your template file?

Comment: @SunderamDubey  here,

`
{{print}}
{{url}}


<form action='upload' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="file" name="image">
 <input type="submit" value="upload file">
</form>

<img src="{{url}}" , width="500" height="400">


`

Comment: You should give proper url name using `url tag` tag in `action` attribute not only `upload`, it should be `action="{% url 'upload' %}"` instead.

Comment: @SunderamDubey it says that this is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: Simply remove action attribute as Django by default takes current page route.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the following code in project's urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ImageClassifier import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ImageClassifier.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: i tried doing this earlier but it didn't worked

Comment: @PrasanjeetPanda See my comment below your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your image is not uploading is that you are not checking whether the request method is `POST` or not. Try below approach and see if it works.

views.py to save to database

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.FILES.get("image")
        pic = Image.objects.create(pic=image)
        pic.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "image.html", {})
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=/image/ method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <input type="file" name="image"> 
        <input type="submit" value="upload file"> 
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

> Url of project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> Url of app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("image/", views.image, name="image"),
]
```

> Lastly, settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

> P.S: Whenever you want to name a class, you should always use `PascalCase` not `camelCase` for the naming convention. You can read on python naming convention [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Hence you model will look something like this:

```
class ImageClassification(models.Model):
    pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Comment: hey i did made changes according to you , but now my image is not even uploading.. I select a image and as soon as i click on the submit button the page refreshes

Comment: Check your admin dashboard to see if it is uploaded or your images folder

Comment: @Olasubmoi hey! yes images are been  stored in my local directory inside "media/images"

Comment: and also the dashboard it not updated

Comment: Can you send your admin.py and also are you trying to upload or update the image

Comment: @PrasanjeetPanda were you able to get it to work.

Comment: i didn't config admin.py is it even necessary i'd once created a superuser

Comment: If you wat to be able to view your model in admin dashboard, yes it is necessary to to configure admin.py